# Why is it illegal to drive with only parking lights, even during the day?

Tags: california, driving

According to [the California Vehicle Code](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displayText.xhtml?lawCode=VEH&division=12.&chapter=2.&article=4.), "No vehicle shall be driven **at any time** with the parking lamps lighted except when the lamps are being used as turn signal lamps or when the headlamps are also lighted."

Why is it illegal to, for example, use the parking lights as daytime running lights (if the car doesn't have DRLs)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In general we don't do "why is the law X?" questions as that is the domain of politics, not law.

Comment: And the law is old enough that there won't be evidence from floor debates.

Comment: Ah, my apologies.

Comment: Presumably for the same reason it's illegal to color your headlights red and your brake lights white: the potential for confusion.

Comment: @Mark What would be confusing about it? The parking lights turn on with the headlights anyway, and having your headlights on during the day is no issue.

Comment: If someone sees your car with parking lights only on, they will reasonably presume your car is parked.

Comment: Or you might not turn your driving lights on when it gets dark, because you think your lights are turned on already.

Comment: @TimLymington Really? I only judge that by where they are on the road, not by their lights. If they're on the side of the road, they're parked; if they're in the middle of the road, they're driving. Remember that from the back, the two look identical.

Comment: @gnasher729 Maybe, but people do that anyway, since dashboards nowadays are perpetually lit. (It's too bad that nobody seems to make black-on-white gauges anymore, only glowing-color-on-black.)